# My panel won't scroll and my scrollpane does not have a slider

Tags: java, swing, slider, panel, scrollpane

I have tried all these but my scrollpane won't scroll and it does not have a slider in it, the scroll bar displays but it has no slider in it, i have set autoscrolls and focus traveral policy but still i get nothing, please what am i doing wrong?

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Web Dev Portal v1.0");
    frame.setResizable(true); 
    frame.setBackground(SystemColor.control); 
     frame.setSize(1050, 2000); 
      frame.setLocation(70, 70);
      frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      JPanel p2 = new JPanel(); 
       p2.setBackground(SystemColor.control); 
        p2.setLayout(null);
        //creating the scrollpane object and adding the panel into it
      JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(p2, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
      pane.setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);
      pane.setAutoscrolls(true); 
      //setting the size of the pane
      pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1202, 2500)); 
       //adding the scrollpane to frame
      frame.setContentPane(pane);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
          @Override
           public void run(){
            frame.setVisible(true);  
          }
```

Comment: `p2.setLayout(null);` is the start of your issues.  `pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1202, 2500));` isn't helping either

Comment: `JScrollPane` will use the `preferredSize` of the view port component to determine when and if it needs to display scroll bars.  Since you've set the layout to `null`, this information is no longer available and the `JScrollPane` is simply not displaying any scroll bars.  You should make use of appropriate layout managers.  If this isn't possible, then you will need to provide sizing hints based on your components needs.  You could also make use of the [`Scrollable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface, but this is more advance topic

Comment: if the `JPanel` had a preferred size, the scroll pane would know how to draw the scroll bars. Since no is given, it will just occupy available space and no scrolling is *needed* (possible) (a bit strange way of using a scroll pane, maybe check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the scroll view should contain component which is bigger than the scroll pane.

Add following code after 'pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1202, 2500));'

```
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500,3000));
pane.getViewport().add(jp);
```